# How to remove white border around app in overview mode

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

As you can see in the image, while in "Overview" mode, my app has a very thin white border at the bottom of the screen. You can also slightly see the white border at the top two corners. I've already set the windowBackground of the AppTheme to the color of my liking.

How can I stop this from happening? Can I change that white to a different color at least?

*P.S. while scrolling between the apps in overview, you can see the white border slightly flickering.

Image of situation:

[image]

Example of Activity XML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Home.HomeFragment">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Middle Section (Body) -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/containerRelativeView">
        <include layout="@layout/layout_feed_viewpager"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Bottom Navigation -->
    <include layout="@layout/layout_navigation_view"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Style.xml

```html
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <!-- Change color of ripple effect on buttons -->
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/label</item>

        <!-- Change color of EditText hint ex. Email, Password -->
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>

        <!-- Change color of navigation bar (this does not work for older phones) -->
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/windowBackground</item>

        <!-- Change background color of all activities -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/windowBackground</item>

        <!--<item name="android:background">@color/toolbar</item>-->
    </style>

    <!-- BottomNavigationTheme -->
    <style name="BottomNavigationTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/stylistic</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/label</item>
        <!-- <item name="android:textSize">17sp</item> -->
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>


    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Colors.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- General App Colors -->
    <color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#1A1E21</color>
    <color name="colorSecondary">#242A2E</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>
    <color name="colorStroke">#707070</color>

    <!-- Colors -->
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>

    <!-- Specific Colors -->
    <color name="windowBackground">#1A1E21</color>
    <color name="label">#9E9F9F</color>
    <color name="search">#9AA0A6</color>
    <color name="navigation">#272E32</color>
    <color name="navigation_text">#606369</color>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <color name="stylistic">#E3E4DF</color>
    <color name="sub_label">#5F6366</color>

    <!-- Shaded Colors -->
    <color name="translucentBlack">#10848D95</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: What is overview mode, Samsung? Does it happen on an emulator with stock android showing recents?

Comment: Its a pixel 2. I'm not sure about emulators, but I can tell you other apps such as spotify, instagram etc. dont  do this

Comment: Share your XML for that view, so we can get some insights

Comment: Just added it! However I have to mention that its not just this activity, its all of them.

Comment: Perhaps its in your Theme then?

Comment: Sure! Just added the style.xml

Comment: What color is `@color/windowBackground`? (and your other colors :-) just to debug easier)

Comment: Updated the code to include colors.xml!

Comment: no clue sorry :-) , only idea is you use `Theme.AppCompat.Light`but your pallette seems dark for your window backgrounds. So why not try using a different inherited theme?

Comment: Wow.. that was simple, I just changed Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar to Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar. It wroked!

Comment: I'll change it to an Answer :-) Its much easier to answer questions when all the code needed is shared ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you use

`Theme.AppCompat.Light`

but your pallette seems dark for your window backgrounds. So why not try using a different inherited theme? Like:

`Theme.AppCompat`